# Difference between GiveFeedBack and QueryContinueDrag in WPF/WinForms

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, events

What is the difference between the events `GiveFeedBack` and `QueryContinueDrag` in WPF or WinForms?

The book I'm reading states:

- GiveFeedBack:  Provides an opprotunity for the user to set a custom mouse pointer
- QueryContinueDrag: Enables the drag source to determine whether a drag event should be cancelled.

MSDN adds that both events are fired *"continuously while the drag source is being dragged"*

So why does this seperation exist? Surely I could set a custom mouse pointer from within the QueryContinueDrag event as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can set the `e.Effects` property (from the `DragEventArgs` class) to `DragDropEffects.None` to cancel a drag and drop operation from any handler that exposes it, eg. `PreviewDrop`, `PreviewDragOver`. Therefore, in my opinion, you are correct.... you *don't* need to do it in the `QueryContinueDrag` handler.

In fact, I have a full working drag and drop system with graphical adorner all achieved through `Attached Properties` and I haven't bothered to implement the `QueryContinueDrag` handler at all.

However, if you want to change the cursor to a custom cursor, then you *will* need to implement a `GiveFeedBack` handler because the `GiveFeedbackEventArgs` allows you to do this:

```
private void PreviewGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.No);
    e.Handled = true; // Important! - Hides the normal drag and drop cursors
}
```

Comment: ah so you need it to _prevent_ WPF from setting the curser back to the previous drag and drop state. I am marking your reply as the answer. While it does not explain why there was a _need_ to implement 'QueryContinueDrag' , it shows that I dont actually have to use it

Comment: May I ask for some detail on how you were able to implement drag adorners in WinForms? I've been looking for a 'pointer' in the right direction, but so far have come up dry.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that... there is no `Adorner` class or layer in WinForms.

Comment: Ah, OK. I misread your comment to mean that you'd done it in WinForms. Can't switch to WPF just yet, but I'm looking forward to the day.